# Incompatible key type Decimal for Map

Tags: apex, map, code

Any Idea on how to solve this error?

Thankyou!

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,Decimal>> BERYear = new Map<Integer,Map<String,Decimal>>();
    List<Budget_Exchange__c> beList = [Select Code__c, USD__c from Budget_Exchange__c];
    Map<String, Decimal> bemap = new Map<String, Decimal>();
    for (Budget_Exchange__c b : beList)
    {

        BERYear.put(b.Fiscal_Year__c,bemap.put(b.Code__c, b.USD__c)); //ERROR HERE
    }
```

> Error: Incompatible key type Decimal for Map(Integer,Map(String,Decimal))

Comment: Your field `Fiscal_Year__c` looks to be type of `Decimal`, while your `Map` requires an `Integer`. Change the map into `Map<Decimal,Map<String,Decimal>> and try again. Also make sure to include the field `Fiscal_Year__c` in your query.

Comment: Correcting as you suggest, the error change, I've reported it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the map here

```
Map<Decimal,Map<String,Decimal>> BERYear = new Map<Decimal,Map<String,Decimal>>();
```

You have defined that the key must be a decimal, and the value must be a Map of String to Decimal.

Then you use the map here

```
BERYear.put(b.Fiscal_Year__c,bemap.put(b.Code__c, b.USD__c)); //ERROR HERE
```

Here you are putting b.Fiscal_Year__c into the key. If b.Fiscal_Year__c is a decimal then this is fine.

What are you putting into the value? You are putting the result of bemap.put(b.Code__c, b.USD__c)
The result of a map.put is, if the map previously contained a mapping for this key, the old value is returned by the method and then replaced. The result of the put is NOT a map.

You should PUT your value into the map on a separate statement.

```
bemap.put(b.Code__c, b.USD__c);
BERYear.put(b.Fiscal_Year__c,bemap);
```